# need to access location.hash in jade, wintersmith

Tags: pug, wintersmith

I am using Wintersmith and need to access the `location.hash` as a variable.

This is what I tried, but it is producing a `Cannot read property 'location' of undefined` error:

```
- var hash = window.location.hash
- var articles =  env.helpers.getArticles(contents, hash)
img(data-item = i, src="img/events/"+hash+'/' +a)
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @AngelM. Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing pug/jade code with browser JavaScript code.  Jade/pug is run on the server so there is no "window" variable available:

```
window.location.hash
```

You will need to pass this in from your route as a variable in the res.render statement:

```
res.render('<<viewName>>', { hash: req.query });
```

Take a look at the Express [req.query docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) first.

Comment: how? so, i cant access in the paginator.coffee aswell.

Comment: You might want to edit your question if you have issues with paginator.coffee as well (I'm not sure what that is)

Comment: ohh,,, I am not using Express.. its in wintersmith.

Comment: Then you need to go into the wintersmith docs and see how to access the request query parameters wherever you call the pug template.